# Hadoop 2 number of free containers through API

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Is there a way to obtain the number of free containers in Hadoop 2 through the Java API?

The reason I would like to do this, is to check if the data I will process will fit in the current cluster configuration.

Comment: isn't this number static (known a-priori)? or, perhaps, you want to run many jobs at the same time..?

Comment: I want to run our algorithm on different clusters and make decisions based on the number of containers available

Comment: ok, then. I don't have the answer, but it might be easier for you to use the `-D parameter=value` option when running the hadoop command, and get the cluster statistics from shell. For example, you could set the number of reducers this way..

Comment: @vefthym do you know how to get these parameters from shell? Number of reducers is calculated automatically in our system.

Comment: I was thinking smth like get the #nodes in the cluster (from the 'slaves' file of the master) and then, assuming all have the same confs, get the number of max allowed running tasks from a slave node. On a second thought, it seems too complicated (stupid), so just wait for another valid answer.. sorry for that and good luck!

Comment: @vefthym It may not be such a bad idea as a workaround. Do you know how to retrieve the max num of running tasks? thanks!